# Why is a varibale "NULL" instead of being undefined?

Tags: php

I was expecting to see a notice like *PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a*, however when I run this code it works perfectly fine. Moreover, the variable becomes NULL. Why?

```
<?php

    function($a = 1) use (&$a) {};
    var_dump($a); // NULL <---- Expected a Notice "undefined", got "NULL"
```

[Demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaUoxV2VRd0NOWmM)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/2hGEk

Comment: There's a [section of the PHP Documentation on this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) - `It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice.` PHP will define a variable when you use it if it doesn't already exist

Comment: @MarkBaker It will, but it will always add a warning, which I can't see in my case.

Comment: @MarkBaker tbh, it does not address the question though: why the behaviour is different.

Comment: @Axalix in the second case you do not address the `$b` variable from the global scope. In the first you do.

Comment: @Axalix the latest change changes nothing. `$b` in the second case is a variable that is local to the anonymous function.

Comment: @zerkms you are right about second case - it was just an example, to confirm that I have notices enabled.

Comment: the `&` operator silently create the variable if it doesn't exist already. i think this page try to explain it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the `&` operator silently create the variable if it doesn't exist already. [seems this page try to explain it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php): 
`If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it will get created.` , so when you do `use (&$a)` , `&` sees that `$a` doesn't already exist, and create it..

as for `undefined`, that's not a real type in PHP. (unlike, for example, javascript, which actually have a type called undefined, and a separate type called null)

why null? given that `undefined` doesn't exist, its the only logical choice for the initial value, what did you expect it to be initialized to?

Comment: This is interesting, I thought it's just a pointer to something that already exists. Although it is still kind of strange it creates it and initializes it with NULL.

Comment: The question wasn't about `undefined` type, it was about a notice `PHP Notice: Undefined variable`.

Comment: @Axalix it's a reference. For a reference to refer somewhere it should be defined. You see the notice because in the second case you do not define a variable (either explicitly or implicitly)

Comment: @zerkms "For a reference to refer somewhere it should be defined" - I am 100% agree with that; and since it's undefined it would make more sense to throw an error... I am really surprised that a variable can be created this way.

Comment: yeah, me too. i'd prefer an exception in my face, rather than silently creating new variables if i for example did a typo... but don't bother trying to get em to fix it, they'll go "blablabla backwards compatibility blablabla"

Comment: Another interesting thing, I don't even call that function, it's just a definition, that I never use.

Comment: So if one asks me how to make a NULL variable, I will always answer `function() use (&$a) {};`

Comment: @Axalix you defined an anonymous function with closure that incorporates a reference to a variable. So a variable should exist for something to refer to it.

Comment: @zerkms that means a part of declaration `use` is being executed w/o a call. Like you saw in a second example `function (&$b = 1) {};` doesn't make a variable defined. Probably it's because `use` is sharing variable between global and functional scopes.

Comment: `use()` is invoked during declaration, since how otherwise would you get the value if not evaluate it? `function (&$b = 1) {};` --- here `$b` is a local variable.

Comment: @zerkms makes sense

Answer (score 0):

"If you don't initialize your variables with a default value, the PHP will do a type cast depending on how you are using the variable. This sometimes will lead to unexpected behaviour."